# What are oriented embeddings of zero-dimensional manifolds?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I'm trying to understand what it should mean for a submanifold of an oriented manifold to have a compatible orientation.

For $1$-dimensional manifolds embedding into a $2$-dimensional manifold, I think I can visualise how this works. i.e. an oriented circle embedding into a $2$-sphere just has to follow the orientation of the sphere:

[image: embedding of a circle into a 2-sphere]

I'd like to have a similar picture for what an oriented embedding of a $0$-dimensional manifold into a $1$-dimensional manifold would look like. However, for an embedding of points into a circle for example I can't see any obvious way that the polarity of a point should relate to an orientation of a circle:

[image: embedding of 2 points into a circle]

This is complicated by the fact that there are various ways to define the orientation of a manifold, and some of them define the orientation of $0$-dimensional manifolds as a special case.

In [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47596/orientations-for-zero-dimensional-manifolds) I can see that one way to define orientation in a way that consistently works for $0$-dimensional manifolds is using the reduction of the structure group of the top exterior-power of the tangent bundle. I would guess from this that for an embedding $f : M \to N$ of connected manifolds, there is an induced map
$$\hat f : \mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb R)/\mathrm{GL}_1^+(\mathbb R) \to \mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb R)/\mathrm{GL}_1^+(\mathbb R)$$
and we can say $f$ preserves orientation if the induced map
is the identity on the chosen orientation of $M$. In the case that $M$ is not connected, I guess I can just ask that this holds for the induced map on each connected component. So I can try to work out what that means for an embedding of a point:

A map $f : \{*\} \to M$ just picks out a point on the circle, and since $T\{*\} = {\mathbb R}^0 = \{0\}$, the induced map on tangent bundles $Tf : \mathbb R^0 \to T M$ must be constant on $0 \in TM$.
Now the exterior algebra $\Lambda \mathbb R^0$ is trivial past degree $0$, so if $M$ has dimension $m > 0$ then the top exterior power $\Lambda^m(TM)$ must lie in the kernel of $\Lambda(Tf)$. From this I deduce that, if it makes sense to have an induced map between top exterior-powers, then this must be constantly $0$ for $f$. Hence $\hat f$ must constantly choose one orientation.

If the above is correct then I think this tells me that an embedding of a zero-dimensional manifold is orientation preserving only if all points in the domain have the same orientation as the manifold in the codomain. This seems surprising since, in one dimension up, we can embed a disjoint union of circles with opposite orientations into a 2-sphere by "turning one of them upside down".

My question therefore is, whether this is a correct characterisation of oriented embeddings, or if there is a better way to think about how to embed zero-dimensional manifolds into higher dimensions. And if this is the case, is there some geometric intuition for why points with opposite orientations should not embed into the same manifold?

**Edit**: On reflection I think my characterisation of oriented embeddings must not be correct, because I could draw the same conclusion about any embedding of a manifold into a manifold with strictly greater dimension. At the least, I think the notion I guessed for the induced morphism of reduced structure groups cannot be right. So I'm back to the point where I simply don't know how to define an oriented embedding of $0$-manifolds..

Comment: For the orientation of a circle to follow the orientation of the sphere is not really meaningful. The arrow you are drawing on the great circle has no meaning. There is no induced orientation on the submanifold unless you orient not only the ambient manifold, but also the normal bundle of the submanifold. But, yeah, orientation of a point is an assignment of $\pm 1$; there's no geometry to it.

Comment: An orientation of a point is simply a sign (+ or -). A conected oriented $1$-manifold with boundary induces an orientation on its boundary. An orientation on a $1$-manifold is smply a direction along the curve. The induced orientation on the boundary is assigning a - to the starting point and a + to the end point. This makes the fundamental theorem of calculus consistent with higher dimensional versions of Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see now that I could continuously move the circle around the sphere to invert the arrow. I guess that's what you mean by it not really being meaningful. Should I take from that that there isn't a good notion of an oriented embedding of any manifold into a manifold with greater dimension? I'd be happy to accept an answer explaining that.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yeah I was starting to realise that when I wrote my edit. I've seen that a diffeomorphism can be classed as orientation preserving by looking at the determinant of the induced map between tangent spaces, so I hoped that I could use this to extend that to a broader class of maps between manifolds. But Ted's comment has helped me realise that this maybe doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Deane the relationship between an oriented manifold with boundary and the induced orientation on its boundary was actually why I was thinking about this. I hoped that this would have some analogue for manifolds without boundary - that I could talk about the orientation of some points on a manifold being compatible with the global orientation in a similar way to how the induced orientation of the boundary is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no natural — or even obvious — way to orient a submanifold $X$ of a given oriented manifold $M$. You need extra structure. For example, you might have an orientation on in its normal bundle. Or $X$ might arise as the preimage of a regular value of a smooth mapping $f\colon M\to N$, where $N$ is oriented (and, ostensibly more generally, the preimage of an oriented submanifold $Z\subset N$ where $f$ is transverse to $Z$. Or you might have the boundary $\partial M$, in which case there is a canonical "boundary orientation." [This generalizes our familiar experience, as Deane alluded to above, of saying that the boundary of $[a,b]$ consists of $+b$ and $-a$.]

See, for example, Section 2 of Chapter 3 of Guillemin and Pollack or pp. 103-108 and Chapter 5 of Hirsch's *Differential Topology*.

Comment: Good point, @Mariano, so that canonical orientation on the normal bundle automatically equips the point with a $+$ orientation. :)

Comment: Thanks! I would say that my question was not so much about how to orient $X$ given an orientation of $M$ (obviously any non-orientable manifold is a counterexample to this), but rather whether there is a way to say if a chosen orientation of $X$ is compatible with the orientation of $M$. But I think this along with the comments on the question have helped me at least get intuition for why such a notion of compatibility might not exist in general.